# Почему super() вызывает метод в обоих суперклассах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, отладка

Такой код:

```
class BaseClass:
    def call_me(self):
        print("Calling method on Base Class")

class LeftSubclass(BaseClass):
    def call_me(self):
        super().call_me()
        print("Calling method on Left Subclass")

class RightSubclass(BaseClass):
    def call_me(self):
        super().call_me()
        print("Calling method on Right Subclass")

class SubClass(LeftSubclass, RightSubclass):    
    def call_me(self):
        super().call_me()
        print("Calling method on SubClass")

s = SubClass()
s.call_me()
```

Результат такой

```
Calling method on Base Class
Calling method on Right Subclass
Calling method on Left Subclass
Calling method on SubClass
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Получается, что `SubClass.call_me()` всегда вызывает указанный метод у всех суперклассов (при его наличии)? А как же правило лишь о первом найденном совпадении?
Разве `SubClass.call_me()` не должен вызвать лишь первый найденный у своих суперклассов метод, считая слева направо (здесь: `LeftSubClass`)

К тому же непонятен порядок печати.
Получается такой порядок исполнения кода, из дебаггера

```
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger:
16 SubClass.call_me()
17 SubClass.super().call_me()  # вызывает call_me() первого слева суперкласса LestSubClass 
6 LeftSubClass.call_me()
# тут странность: на строке 7 вызывается не сall_me() суперкласса
# LeftSubClass - BaseClass, а RightSubClass.call_me()
7 LeftSubClass.super().call_me()  # вызван RightSubClass.call_me()
11 RightSubClass.call_me()  # RightSubClass вызывает сall_me() у BaseClass
12 BaseClass.call_me()  # print("Calling method on Base Class")
# тут начались странности: 
# print("Calling method on Right Subclass")
# print("Calling method on Left Subclass") 
# print("Calling method on SubClass")
```

Получается, что на строке 7 вызывается не `сall_me()` суперкласса `LeftSubClass (BaseClass)`, а `RightSubClass.call_me()`. Почему так? И почему такой порядок принтов?

вот что написано в книжке:

*First call_me of `Subclass` calls `super().call_me()` , which happens to refer to `LeftSubclass.call_me()`. `LeftSubclass.call_me()` then calls `super().call_me()`, but in this case, `super()` is referring to `RightSubclass.call_me()`. Pay particular attention to this; the super call is not calling the method on the superclass of `LeftSubclass` (which is `BaseClass`), it is calling `RightSubclass`, even though it is not a parent of `LeftSubclass`! This is the next method, not the parent method. `RightSubclass` then calls `BaseClass` and the super calls have ensured each method in the class hierarchy is executed once.*

**Кто понмиает\знает, почему тут:**

**1. *"the super call is not calling the method on the superclass of `LeftSubclass` (which is `BaseClass`), it is calling `RightSubclass`, even though it is not a parent of `LeftSubclass`!"*?**

**2. почему *"LeftSubclass.call_me() then calls super().call_me(), but in this case, super() is referring to RightSubclass.call_me()"*?**

**3. что такое *"the next method"*?**

Comment: С множественным наследованием всё сложно, вот тут есть подробный разбор алгоритма https://habr.com/ru/post/62203/

Comment: я пока, пожалуй, не буду лезть в эти дебри. кстати, пример из книги, и вот что там написано:
_First call_me of Subclass calls super().call_me() , _which happens to refer to
LeftSubclass.call_me() . LeftSubclass.call_me() then calls super().call_
me() , but in this case, super() is referring to RightSubclass.call_me() . Pay
particular attention to this; the super call is not calling the method on the superclass
of LeftSubclass (which is BaseClass ), it is calling RightSubclass , even though
it is not a parent of LeftSubclass ! This is the next method, not the parent method._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правило о первом найденном совпадении работает в вашем примере, когда вы вызываете метод `call_me()` в `SubClass`. И если вы не будете вызывать `super().call_me()`, то на этом действие прекратится. Метод же `super().call_me()` передает выполнение следующему родителю по порядку наследования (mro)  для вызова соответствующего метода.

> Получается, что на строке 7 вызывается не сall_me() суперкласса
>   LeftSubClass (BaseClass), а RightSubClass.call_me(). Почему так? И
>   почему такой порядок принтов?

В python2 порядок наследования определялся через поиск родителей, который велся вверх во всех родительских классах на максимальную глубину.

В python 3 этот порядок несколько изменился и ведется по алгоритму c3. Если кратко, то

- Сначала в список добавляются родители объекта
- в конец списка добавляет список родителей этих родителей и так далее
- если какой-то класс оказывается в списке дважды, то оставляется
  только последнее его вхождение

То есть в вашем случае для класса

```
class SubClass(LeftSubclass, RightSubclass):
```

при вызове super() внутри него ищется первый родитель слева направо. Это `LeftSubclass`, затем `RightSubclass`. Затем ищутся родители этих классов, и добавляются в конец. Т.к. они совпадают (`BaseClass`), то остаётся только он один.

В итоге стэк вызовов выглядит так:
`SubClass`=>`LeftSubclass`=>`RightSubclass`=>`BaseClass`

Что и показал дебаггер

Comment: а почему в порядке принтах райт идет первее лефта?

Comment: @Mintaj, потому то у вас во всех методах строка `super().call_me()` стоит перед `print`-ами

Comment: @Mintaj, те внутри метода `SubClass.call_me()` сначала вызывается метод первого родителя (`LeftSubclass`), который вызывает метод следующего родителя (`RightSubclass`), который вызывает метод из BaseClass. Соответственно тогда и печатается строка из BaseClass, затем огромное выполнение возвращается к RightSubclass и печатает строку оттуда, затем к LeftSubclass, печатает строку из LeftSubclass, и возвращает выполнение в SubClass, печатая его текст. Вроде очевидно

Comment: я разобрался, почему такой порядок принтов. стек вызовов call_me() формируется так:
1. `SubClass.call_me()`,  2. `LeftSubClass.call_me()`, 3. `RightSubClass.call_me()` 4. `BaseClass.call_me()`, а потом принты выводятся в обратном порядке: 4,3,2,1 (это видно в табличке справа вверху "call stack". Странно, но факт.

Comment: @Mintaj , не понятно, что было не понятно. я в ответе изначально такой же порядок писал. Но хорошо, что вы разобрались)